# Monitoring files asynchronously

Tags: windows, unix, asynchronous, filesystems, monitoring

On Unix: I’ve been through `FAM` and `Gamin`, and both seem to provide a client/server file monitoring system. I would rather have a system where I tell the kernel to monitor some inodes and it pokes me back when events occur. `Inotify` looked promising at first on that side: `inotify_init1` let me pass `IN_NONBLOCK` which in turn caused `poll()` to return directly. However I understood that I would have to call it regularly if I wanted to have news about the monitored files. Now I’m a bit short of ideas.

Is there something to monitor files asynchronously?

PS: I haven’t looked on Windows yet, but I would love to have some answers about it too.

Comment: `inotify` is exactly what you're looking for. If you include the inotify file description in a `poll()` request, it will return when there is an inotify event available for reading. As usual with `poll()`, it will block for as long as none of the file descriptors you have asked about are ready and the timeout hasn't expired. So where's the problem?

Comment: well, having a blocking `poll()` call is not exactly what I call asynchronous, quite the contrary :)

Comment: How do you expect to get notified when there are inotify events (or data available on a socket, or any other kind of event)? If your software is structured around waiting for events and acting on them then you already have an event loop of some kind which calls `poll()` or similar. If you want to instead run other code while waiting for events to come in then you probably need to do that in a separate thread, in which case your main thread will either still use an event loop or else maybe you don't even need nonblocking IO at all and you can have one thread that blocks on `inotify`'s `read()`.

Comment: _How do you expect to get notified when there are inotify events_: I expect a signal to be sent by the kernel.

I am actually developing a library called xnot, so the main structure is not present. But let’s assume it has an event loop: in that case I can’t afford to block it by calling `poll()`. Conversely, dedicating a thread to that is something I’d like to avoid because it’s expensive.

Comment: You would not BLOCK its event loop, you would INTEGRATE WITH IT, so that it waits for your inotify file descriptor along with all of the other things it happens to wait for. Event loop frameworks like that of glib provide a way to hook into them. But anyway, you are talking about signals. You mean like POSIX signals? As used by functions like `aio_read()`? Well, you could try `aio_read()` on an `inotify` fd. It might work. I have no idea, but I wouldn't recommend it. It's usually not a good idea to use signals from within a library because it might interfere with the app's use of them.

Comment: @Celada: _Event loop frameworks like that of glib provide a way to hook into them._ : that sounds really interesting, would you mind pointing me to some documentation so I can read further on that? now aio is what I’m really into at the moment, and you totally have a point about POSIX signals: but well, if I can save creating a thread, that might be worth loosing a SIGUSR I suppose.

Comment: You can read the [documentation for glib's event loop](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) or the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) referenced by [Perry](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1161293/perry) for more general information. I support Perry's answer: you should not use AIO and signals but an event loop (or maybe a thread). An event loop gives you the interface you need: you register your interest, go off and do something else, and you get a callback sometime later. Just like with AIO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However interesting are you answers, I am sorry but I can’t accept a mechanism based on blocking calls on poll or select, when the question states “asynchronously”, regardless of how deep it is hidden.

On the other hand, I found out that one could manage to run inotify asynchronously by passing to `inotify_init1` the flag `IN_NONBLOCK`. Signals are not triggered as they would have with `aio`, and a `read` call that would block blocking would set `errno` to `EWOULDBLOCK` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As Celada says in the comments above, inotify and poll are the right way to do this.

Signals are not a mechanism for reasonable asynchronous programming -- and signal handlers are remarkably dangerous for the inexperienced and even for the experienced. One does not use them for such purposes voluntarily.

Instead, one should structure one's program around an event loop (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming for an overall explanation) using poll, select, or some similar system call as the core of your program's event handling mechanism.

Alternatively, you can use threads, or threads plus an event loop.